# Refreshing AJAX Forms in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

My dynamic Competition form has two basic parts:

1- Basic Info

- Name
- Size Dropdown

2- Ajax Fields

- Options dropdown based on Size

When I change the value in Size, a new combobox is loaded via AJAX with related values.

Here is part of my form:

```
if ($competition->size == 0)
    {
        $form['country'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Country'),
            '#weight' =>3,
            '#required' => FALSE,
            '#zurb_class'=> 'cleared',
            '#default_value' => $competition->country_id,
            '#options' => _ajax_countries_dropdown_options(),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
    }
    else if ($competition->size == 1)
    {
        $form['continent'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Continent'),
            '#default_value' => $competition->continent_id,
            '#weight' =>2,
            '#required' => FALSE,
            '#options' => _ajax_continents_dropdown_options(),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',

        );
    }
    else
    {
        $suffix = '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace"></div>';
    }

    $form['size'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Size'),
        '#default_value' => $competition->size,
        '#weight' =>1,
        '#options' => $options_size,
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_competition_size_dropdown_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'dropdown-competition-size-replace',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
        '#suffix' => $suffix,
    );
```

Ajax Callback

```
function ajax_competition_size_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
    $size = $form_state['values']['size'];

    if ($size == 0)
    {
        return array(
            '#name' => 'country',
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Country'),
            '#weight' =>3,
            '#required' => FALSE,
            '#zurb_class'=> 'cleared',
            '#default_value' => $competition->country_id,
            '#options' => _ajax_countries_dropdown_options(),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
    }
    else if ($size == 1)
    {
        return array(
            '#name' => 'continent',
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Continent'),
            '#default_value' => $competition->continent_id,
            '#weight' =>2,
            '#required' => FALSE,
            '#options' => _ajax_continents_dropdown_options(),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return '<div id="dropdown-competition-size-replace"></div>';
    }
}
```

Steps I made so far:

- When I change the first select when editing, the values are not saved.
- Debugging Backend
- The form changes on the front (AJAX), but it does not change on the backend
- Apparently the problem is I am creating the form fields based on size, Drupal will only recognize this fields. So when I change the select and load the second, it won't parsed by Drupal
- I tried to use $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; but it didn't fix anything, actually avoided the redirection after submission.

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax callback should only return the named FAPI element that is to be replaced. For example:

```
function questionaire_4D_selector_form_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // If the form has errors we show them in the Preview spot. There's not much
  // else we can do because jQuery is replacing out the specified
  // target element in the #ajax FAPI element.
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    return $form['preview-content-area']['esci-questionaire'];
  }
  return $form['preview-content-area']['esci-questionaire'];
}
```

Your `form_builder` function which build/rebuilds the form should examine the `$form_state` and alter the form as necessary based on the ajax submitted values:

```
/** Our form builder function */
function questionaire_4d_selector_form($form, &$form_state) {
 # for ajax inspection goto /tmp and view file output.
 #dd($form_state);
 #dpm($form_state);

  // This form responds to an AJAX submit button, and also a $_GET argument.
  $form_passed_get_parameter_questionaire_id = $form_state['submitted'] == FALSE &&
          count($form_state['build_info']['args']) &&
          ctype_digit($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]);
  #dpm($form_passed_get_parameter_questionaire_id ? 1 : 0);
  if ($form_passed_get_parameter_questionaire_id) {
    $id = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  } else {
    $id = !empty($form_state['values']['questionaire_id']) ? $form_state['values']['questionaire_id'] : '';
  }
  #dpm($id);
  $form['questionaire_selector'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Select 4D Questionaire'),
  );
  $form['questionaire_selector']['access_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => drupal_get_token(QUESTIONAIRE_4D_PREVIEW_AJAX_SECRET_VALUE),
  );
  $form['questionaire_selector']['questionaire_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Questionaire Number'),
    '#default_value' => $id,
    '#element_validate' => array('element_validate_integer_positive'),
    '#size' => 15,
  );
  $form['questionaire_selector']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Preview 4D Questionaire'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'questionaire_4d_selector_form_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'questionaire-preview',
      'method' => 'replace',
    ),
  );
  $form['preview-content-area'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  );
  $form['preview-content-area']['esci-questionaire'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="questionaire-preview">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<h3>Your Questionaire Preview will appear here.</h3>',
  );

  // This says if we were given an remote 4D form id of say 23456, load it into the supplied FAPI
  // element.
  if ($form_passed_get_parameter_questionaire_id) {
    $remote_response = retrieve_questionaire_4d_response($id);
    if (strpos($remote_response->data, 'Error',0) === 0) {
      form_set_error('questionaire_selector', "<b>Remote 4D Error</b><br>" . $remote_response->data);
    }
    $form['preview-content-area']['esci-questionaire']['#markup'] = questionaire_4d_selector_build_esci_questionaire_preview($id, $remote_response->data);
  }

  $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'questionaire_4d_preview') . '/assets/questionaire_4d_preview.css',
  );
  return $form;
}

/* Implements hook_menu() */
function questionaire_4d_preview_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/esci-online/questionaire-4d-preview'] = array(
    'title' => '4D Questionaire Preview',
    'description' => 'View a preview of a remote 4D questionare.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    // I'm not sure we have to, but explicitly pass in the 4th
    // argument on the URL as the questionairre ID. This is added
    // to build_info of form automatically.
    'page arguments' => array('questionaire_4d_selector_form', 4),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('administer esci'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```